# Why do I have two pycharm installations (what should I do about it)?

Tags: 14.04, duplicate-files, pycharm

I followed the instructions [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/07/install-pycharm-ubuntu-1404/) to install PyCharm (on Ubuntu 14.04). After checking that it worked (by running "pycharm" from the terminal), I wanted to add it to the sidebar, but found [two installations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNFBr.png).

I don't know if these are the same thing or if one of them needs to be deleted to avoid problems.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have two installations . You might be having two desktop entries. Check `~/.local/share/applications` and `/usr/share/applications`.

If you find two desktop entry files delete one among them.